# Outline Shader in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to configure a shader I got from the net to have a white outline not a black one. But `_OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)` doesn't work.
I'm new to Unity and how things work in it so I hope you can help me.

Here is the complete shader:

```cpp
Shader "Outlined/Diffuse" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (0,0,0,0)
        _OutlineColor ("Outline Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _Outline ("Outline width", Range (.002, 0.03)) = 5
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
    }
 
CGINCLUDE
#include "UnityCG.cginc"
 
struct appdata {
    float4 vertex : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};
 
struct v2f {
    float4 pos : POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};
 
uniform float _Outline;
uniform float4 _OutlineColor;
 
v2f vert(appdata v) {
    // just make a copy of incoming vertex data but scaled according to normal direction
    v2f o;
    o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
 
    float3 norm   = mul ((float3x3)UNITY_MATRIX_IT_MV, v.normal);
    float2 offset = TransformViewToProjection(norm.xy);
 
    o.pos.xy += offset * o.pos.z * _Outline;
    o.color = _OutlineColor;
    return o;
}
ENDCG
 
    SubShader {
        //Tags {"Queue" = "Geometry+100" }
CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert
 
sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;
 
struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
};
 
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG
 
        // note that a vertex shader is specified here but its using the one above
        Pass {
            Name "OUTLINE"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            Cull Front
            ZWrite On
            ColorMask RGB
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            //Offset 50,50
 
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            half4 frag(v2f i) :COLOR { return i.color; }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
 
    SubShader {
CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Lambert
 
sampler2D _MainTex;
fixed4 _Color;
 
struct Input {
    float2 uv_MainTex;
};
 
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
    o.Albedo = c.rgb;
    o.Alpha = c.a;
}
ENDCG
 
        Pass {
            Name "OUTLINE"
            Tags { "LightMode" = "Always" }
            Cull Front
            ZWrite On
            ColorMask RGB
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
 
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma exclude_renderers gles xbox360 ps3
            ENDCG
            SetTexture [_MainTex] { combine primary }
        }
    }
 
    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: Verify the color is white in the material Inspector.  Unity's Inspector settings supersede values you hardcode in the shader.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What doesn't work? Check in the inspector what colour is assigned during the gameplay. Also try to change the colour during the gameplay on the object assigned to it in order to check if there isn't some error within the shader itself.

Answer (score 0):

The "(1,1,1,1)" you are assigning to "_OutlineColor" describes a default value. That value is  taken into consideration when you create new material that utilises that shader (here "Outlined/Diffuse"). Just create new material and assign to it your shader. You will notice that the Outline color this time will be white. Also you can simply select your material in the Editor and change the outline colour via inspector window.

As for your problem - probably you've created a new material combined with the shader you describe, BEFORE you made a change in the shader's body from black (0,0,0,1) to white (1,1,1,1) colour (I recognize the body of the shader, so I assume the black color). And what that means is that the default black colour has already been assigned to the material. If you want to change the colour, as I wrote above, do it on the material through the Editor's inspector.